# Maven compile works, but mvn install doesn't

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.openliberty.tools:liberty-maven-plugin:3.7.1:deploy (package-server) on project my-service: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()" because "fatArchiveSrc" is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

With `mvn install -X` the last trace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()" because "fatArchiveSrc" is null
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.installSpringBootApp (DeployMojo.java:114)
    at io.openliberty.tools.maven.applications.DeployMojo.doExecute (DeployMojo.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute (MojoSupport.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

`mvn compile` works fine, and neither Google or Bing can find anything about "fatArchiveSrc"; how to solve this error?

`fatArchiveSrc` is part of the [ci.maven source code](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven) and needs a Spring Boot jar according to [Spring boot app's .jar not working (issue with tomcat-embed-jasper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74913190/spring-boot-apps-jar-not-working-issue-with-tomcat-embed-jasper#comment132202868_74913190)

`mvn install -DskipTests` works for my colleague but he then moved some dependency info from the main pom.xml to the war pom.xml and now I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:report (report) on project my-service-war: An error has occurred in JaCoCo report generation.: Error while creating report: Error while analyzing /Users/user/Documents/code/my-service/my-service-war/target/classes/nl/company/Application.class. Unsupported class file major version 63 -> [Help 1]
```

WAR and EAR aren't in the target folders, so we might be further from home.

Main pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>nl.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my-service</name>
    <description>Facade service</description>

    <modules>
        <module>my-service-ear</module>
        <module>my-service-war</module>
    </modules>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

        <sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/dependency-check-report.html</sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath>
        <scm-connection>scm:git:ssh://git@git.company.nl:7999/my-service.git</scm-connection>

        <log4j.version>2.18.0</log4j.version>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>4.6.1</mockito.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <!-- Overige -->
        <!-- Zorgt ervoor dat de classes ook de namen van parameters bevatten, maakt Jackson gebruik eenvoudiger -->
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Module dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>nl.company</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-service-war</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

my-service-war/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-service-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>API proxy.</description>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Module dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <MICRO_CONFIG>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/META-INF</MICRO_CONFIG>
                        <DX_LOG_DIR>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</DX_LOG_DIR>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>my-service-${project.version}.war</warName>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Enable Liberty Maven plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appsDirectory>apps</appsDirectory>
                    <installAppPackages>spring-boot-project</installAppPackages>
                    <include>minify,runnable</include>
                    <packageName>my-service</packageName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-server</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                            <goal>install-feature</goal>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

my-service-ear/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.copany</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-service-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>EAR deployable</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.copany</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-service-war</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>my-service-war</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>my-service-${project.version}.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/my-service</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: change the order of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` plugins in `my-service-war/pom.xml`, m.b. it also required to configure dedicated classifier for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I tried that but `mvn install -DskipTests` returns the same JaCoCo error. `mvn clean install -DskipTests` however works now, but does still after reverting your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to `mvn clean` as `mvn install -DskipTests` works now. The test errors are a different issue, related to [using command line how run junit test present inside the war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788410/using-command-line-how-run-junit-test-present-inside-the-war-file)